# Why does an implicit with a map yield a Range statement error?

Tags: scala

With the below MRE I would expect the following output:

```
$ scala mre.scala
1
```

```scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val thing = List[String]().map(_.to(List))
    for (x <- 1 to 1) {
        println(x)
    }
  }
}
```

However what I do get is the following

```
$ scala mre.scala
mre.scala:4: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: scala.collection.Factory[Char,?]
    for (x <- 1 to 1) {
```

If I remove either the `implicit` or the `.map(_.to(List))` then it works as expected.

What on earth is going on here? I have no idea where to even begin.

```
$ scala --version
Scala code runner version 2.13.7 -- Copyright 2002-2021, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.
```

Comment: Stackoverflow should consider [works with scala-3](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/PSquVCmmQAGd6o2Mpe39Uw) as one of the options in Flags.

Comment: Why are you even having an implicit `List[List[Char]]`?

Comment: Unlikely you'll get an answer here, you might want to open a bug on Scala GitHub.

Comment: If this is what I think it is, then this is a know issue, solved in Scala 3. I saw an answer on SO a few years ago explaining how a few features put together ended up with exactly this unexpected behavior, but my Google-Fu failed me and I cannot find it.

Comment: Martin Odersky [explains](https://youtu.be/Oij5V7LQJsA?t=2261) why this is happening and what the future plan is, both of which @MateuszKubuszok has also clearly explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70317042/757071).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An educated guess (sth like 99% of certainty): any collection extends (`Partial`)`Function` therefore by making collection implicit you are providing an implicit conversion (because any unary `implicit def` OR implicit function is implicit conversion):

```
// this
implicit val thing = List[String]().map(_.to(List))
// implies this
implicit def intToCharList(idx: Int): List[Char]] =  thing(idx)
```

Then here:

```
 1 to 1
```

you have ambiguity: it might be either:

- extension method `.to(Int)` on `Int`
- normal method `.to(CollectionType)` on `List` (since Scala 2.13) after `Int` is implicitly converted

If compiler picks the latter, then you have something like

```
thing(1).to(1) // .to expects collection factory and got 1 instead
```

which triggers the error that you see. And it might pick the latter because you declared your implicit in the same scope and [`richInt` implicit conversion](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/Predef$.html#intWrapper(x:Int):scala.runtime.RichInt) is declared in `LowPriorityImplicit` in `scala.Predef`, so Scala will prefer yours.

In Scala 3 implicit conversions are a *subtype* of `Function` so this issue is not happening. In Scala 2 I can only strongly recommend against making *any* collection implicit.